# What is shirt stuffing?

Tags: phrase-usage

Could somebody please explaing what the phrase "Do you stuff your own shirts, or do you send them out?" means in the following context:

> Giles:  I'll have you know that I have very, uh, many relaxing hobbies.
>   Buffy:  Such as?
>   Giles:  I enjoy cross-referencing.
>   Buffy:  **Do you stuff your own shirts**, or do you send them out?
>
> (from *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* S2E18)

Also, what **shirts** and **cross-referencing** might possibly have in common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a joke by Buffy based on wordplay. Giles is being pompous, and Buffy is, in effect, calling him a 'stuffed shirt' which is an idiomatic phrase meaning a pompous or self-important person. Some people wash their own clothes (including shirts) at home, and some 'send them out' to be washed at a laundry and returned clean.